# Covariate analysis comparing distributions / means of circular data

Tags: inference, mean, ancova, circular-statistics

Are there publicly available software packages to run an analysis comparing the means or distributions of two samples of circular data with the presence of a covariate? If not, are there ways to modify existing tests to account for the potential covariate?

I am able to run a Watson-Williams test or a non-parametric Watson's U2 on just the circular data, but I believe that another variable will moderate the effect of the angular mean differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modeling the circular angles directly, a common approach is to project them onto a normal distribution, after which a variety of statistical tests (such as ANCOVA and mixed-effects models) can occur.

The `R` package `bpnreg` has a [regression function (bpnr)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bpnreg/versions/2.0.1/topics/bpnr), that does this conversion and regression. A guided example can be [found in this reference](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2018.02040/full). Here is the snippet that they used:

```
fit.Motor <- bpnr(pred.I = Phaserad ~ 1 + Cond, data = Motor, its = 10000, burn = 100, n.lag = 3, seed = 101)
```